# Interactive Slidify deployment?

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, slidify

I found this great tutorial for  [slidify](http://slidify.github.io/dcmeetup/demos/interactive/)

How can I create a "standalone" presentation? I tried changing the `mode` to `standalone` but it does not work because of Rcharts and shiny. I would like to be able to create something that I can host in my website.

I tried to publish to dropbox but the interactive graphics do not work

```
publish_dropbox("slidify")
```

Comment: If you have a `shiny` app in your deck, then your only option is to host it on a shiny server. Decks with `rCharts` can be made to work on a static site, which is achievable by just copying your slide folder to a public folder in dropbox.

Comment: can I hold a slidify deck on shinyapps.io? or I need to create my own server? Btw, I'm a new an big fan of your work @Ramnath

Comment: Yes. It is possible to run a slidify created deck as a shiny app. Currently, it is a little cumbersome. I will try to post an example on the steps needed to do it.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ramnath is there now an example (since your comment on Jun 10, on how to trigger a slidify slide deck from a shiny server with a shiny website?

Comment: @Ramnath Is there an example on this now? Since its been more than 2 years now.